# A D20 (dice) has sides where $N-1,N,N+1$ are always neighbours on surface of solid. For which DN is this possible?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, dice

A regular gon D20 dice used for example in various forms of gambling and trading card games is shown below
[image: D20]

As can be seen each number $N$ residing on some face has two of it's neighbouring faces with numbers $N-1$ and $N+1$. Can we prove somehow for which regular N-gons this is possible to do?

Comment: What do you mean by *always neighbours*?  In your picture, what makes $18$ and $20$ neighbours?  For reasonable definitions, it looks probable to me that all five regular polyhedra can have this labelling

Comment: @Henry always exist two of the "face" neighbours (neighbours in sense of sharing an edge) for each face so that one of these face neighbours has number which is 1 smaller and the other 1 larger than the value of the current face.

Comment: In that case it looks easy just to show a labelling that works for each of the five cases (effectively a Hamiltonian path on the dual graph).  Slightly harder, at least for the dodecahedron, would be requiring additionally all three successive faces to also share a vertex, but I think this too is possible

Comment: Wait you mean so that they circle around surface like a snake?

Comment: That is the way I would do it

Comment: The number $N=20$ in your photo seems to be a counterexample. Even taken modulo 20.

Comment: Yes, ehm, except for biggest and smallest $N$.